# ASP .NET Mixes data from different thread of users

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, virtual-machine

I have been Looking into a weird issue Recently, looking for some answers

In an Asp.Net 4.0 Web Application, i have a method which accepts object as an input parameter, Now i am Running a Load Test on the Below code with 10 Users, While I do so I get the if condition satisfied in few cases which should not be so. Which mean my data from different users mixes up leading to undesirable results. This is in My Local Machine and Hosted server - both are virtual Machines.

```
Private SampleClass b 
Public void DoWork(int a,SampleClass obj)
{
try
{
b=obj;
if(b.id  !=obj.id)
{
 throw new Exception("Error");
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
}
```

Kindly Help me Here...

Comment: What exactly is your question? And what type is ID? How does it get its first value?

Comment: Unanswerable due to lack of details. Best guess: you have some `static` data somewhere.

Comment: I dont have static data anywhere , i have already checked it,The datatype of id is integer... i am assigning it in aspx and sending it accross plain and simple

Comment: Please provide the entire class along with some code that calls your function `DoWork`.

Comment: public class SampleClass
    {
        public SampleClass()
        {
            _datebegan = DateTime.Now;
            _Sampleitems = new List<Sampleitems>();

        }
      
        #region Properties

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Ordinal { get; set; }
        public virtual string SubOrdinal { get; set; }
        #endregion

        public virtual SampleClassClone()
        {
            SampleClass sample = new SampleClass();
            sample.Id= this.Id;
            sample.Ordinal  = this.value;
            return sample;


        }

}

Comment: Are you using any sort of threading? Maybe Tasks using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`?

Comment: do an edit to your post and add SampleClass. It's unreadable like this. Also add a proper question

Comment: ExternalService.SampleServiceService.DoWork(id,obj );

Comment: You've added the multithreading tag to the question, where in your code are you using threads?

Comment: No i am not using any threading , this function is present in a webserice which i am calling from aspx

Comment: Its pretty hard to tell given the information provided. My best guess is somehow you are using the same instance of the class containing the method above and you are running into a race condition.

Comment: Even with the details of SampleClass, it's not clear where the id is generated, how it is generated, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just figured this out ... the Do work method is being called by an static instance and then internall the Do work uses Nhibernate to save the data... some how Nhibernate mixes these data on error /certain scenario

Now replacing static with a new instance object ,seem to resolved the issue.

Thanks everyone